# Two ingress controller, the IP of the second ingress controller not being showing

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a K8s cluster in Azure with two ingress controllers both are public:
`Controller A` is configured to redirect to `Service A` with default `nginx class`
and `Controller IoT` is configured to redirect to `Service B` with custom class:

```
...
    args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=iot-nginx
...
```

ingress for iot:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
...
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "iot-nginx" 
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "prod_issuer"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: nginx-errors
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: '403,404,503,400,500'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - <service B url>
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod-cert-iot 
  rules:
  - host: <service B url>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /iot
        backend:
          serviceName: iot
          servicePort: 80
```

This works perfectly fine, I also get TLS certificate using Cert manager. both services are accessible from the public using HTTPS.

The issue is when I run  the command to see ingress, I only see the public ip address of the default ingress controller ?

```
@Azure:~/https$ kubectl get ingress
NAME                                           HOSTS                    ADDRESS          PORTS     AGE
letsencrypt-prod-cert                          <SericeA URL>            XX.XXX.XX.XX     80, 443   53d
letsencrypt-prod-cert-iot                      <SericeB URL>                             80, 443   63s
service-A-ingress                              <SericeA URL>            XX.XXX.XX.XX     80, 443   21d
Service-B-ingress-iot                          <SericeB URL>                             80        31m
```

The IP address for Service B is not being shown, what could be causing this ?

**Update**

I look into the pods logs of the first controller with default class Nginx
I got this error:

```
I0416 08:08:59.531993       6 flags.go:208] "Watching for Ingress" class="nginx"
W0416 08:08:59.532037       6 flags.go:213] Ingresses with an empty class will also be processed by this Ingress controller
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v0.44.0
  Build:         f802554ccfadf828f7eb6d3f9a9333686706d613
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.6

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0416 08:08:59.532349       6 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0416 08:08:59.533011       6 main.go:241] "Creating API client" host="https://10.0.0.1:443"
I0416 08:08:59.553015       6 main.go:285] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="17" git="v1.17.11" state="clean" commit="3a3612132641768edd7f7e73d07772225817f630" platform="linux/amd64"
F0416 08:08:59.557528       6 main.go:93] No service with name ingress-nginx-1612789874-controller found in namespace default: services "ingress-nginx-1612789874-controller" not found
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/klog/v2.stacks(0xc0000b0001, 0xc000026200, 0xb8, 0x1e2)
        k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.4.0/klog.go:1026 +0xb9
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).output(0x26915e0, 0xc000000003, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0003efb90, 0x25e6c33, 0x7, 0x5d, 0x40e200)
        k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.4.0/klog.go:975 +0x19b
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).printDepth(0x26915e0, 0xc000000003, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0xc00002e310, 0x1, 0x1)
        k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.4.0/klog.go:732 +0x16f
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).print(...)
        k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.4.0/klog.go:714
k8s.io/klog/v2.Fatal(...)
        k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.4.0/klog.go:1482
main.main()
        k8s.io/ingress-nginx/cmd/nginx/main.go:93 +0x170f
...
```

Comment: You need to check the service of the second ingress if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: I checked it nothing is wrong with it, works perfectly fine, im doubting dns record is not yet updated that maybe what is causing this

Comment: When you install the ingress controller, the services are created and be assigned with the public IP. So check the services if the type and the status are all right.

Comment: The type and services are correct, im still not sure why its not displaying the IP address of the second controller tho in services the Public IP is shown there when i list all services .